# View для java web-app

Tags: java-ee, jsf, web-apps, java, jsp

Что-то запутался. Cкажите, что сегодня наиболее используется в качестве View (представления) для веб-проектов в данный момент - jsp, jsf или что-то иное? Вроде говорят, что jsp стар, но jsf вроде какой-то не очень распространенный.

Comment: Опишите подробнее архитектурные ограничения проекта. Например, JavaServer Faces и примочки к нему вроде PrimeFaces очень плохо подходят для single-page приложений, но хорошо работают в многостраничных проектах, особенно в дополнение к EJB. Подход - компонентный. То есть, фреймворк даёт в ваше распоряжение "богатые" компоненты, сочетающие в себе и серверный, и клиентский код, не предполагающий серьёзного перетачивания. Если цель - single-page приложение, то идеально взять SpringMVC, отдающий JSON, и клиентский фреймворк вроде AngularJS или Ember JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В зависимости от задач:

- [PrimeFaces](http://primefaces.org/) для тех, кому нравится JSP/JSF;
- [SiteMesh](http://wiki.sitemesh.org/wiki/display/sitemesh/Home) для сборки страницы;
- Традиционные [FreeMarker](http://freemarker.org/), [Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/) или совсем модный Thymeleaf для собственно шаблонизации представлений;
- [GWT](http://www.gwtproject.org/) и иже с ним ([ZK](http://www.zkoss.org/), [Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/home)) для single page application.

Comment: Мне както Thymeleaf рекомендовали. теперь я вспомнил название. Эти шаблонизаторы требуют какого-то MVC фреймворка?

Comment: @argamidon, само собой. Они же просто шаблонизаторы. Прикрутите к любому MVC-фреймворку на свой вкус: Spring MVC, Play, Spark.

Comment: я спросил потому, что JSP не требует какихто MVC фреймворков.

Comment: Само собой, потому что JSP это не шаблонизатор, а скорее DSL, который компилируется в сервлет. Но мы же понимаем, что фигачить логику прямо в JSP - неправильно.

Comment: @Nofate ♦ вопрос чуть не по теме: как насчёт Struts как MVC фрейворк?

Comment: @argamidon, имеет место быть. Но у меня к нему предвзятое отношение. Воспринимаю его как нечто ископаемое из начала 2000-х, из "досприноговой" эпохи (есть у меня немного спринг головного мозга). Хотя последний релиз совсем недавно был.

Comment: @Nofate ♦ всё понятно. спасибо !